# How to delete item from recyclerview and database using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter with onSwiped?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

My firebase realtime database looks like this. Every item has its own pushId from push() and are shown in my recyclerview like picture below. What i want is that when i swipe to either left or right in the recyclerview, i want to delete that item from realtime database aswell. I have tried with different Firebase references with removeValue(), but i'm struggling with getting the exact path.

I'm storing all data from "Utfordringer" in an ArrayList aswell so I can get the "pushId", but not sure on how to work with it.. Not many examples with Kotlin out there either.

[image: Realtime Db]

[image: Recyclerview]

```
lateinit var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    lateinit var mDatabase: DatabaseReference


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_utfordringer)
        supportActionBar?.title = "Utfordringer"

        recyclerview_utfordringer.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Utfordringer")
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_utfordringer)

        updateToRecyclerView()
        recyclerViewItemTouchListener()
    }

    // Funksjon som henter data og setter inn i RecyclerViewet med FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
    private fun updateToRecyclerView() {

        val firebaseRecyclerAdapter = object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Utfordringer, CustomViewHolder>(
                Utfordringer::class.java,
                R.layout.utfordring_item, // Et custom item vi har laget for å vises i recyclerviewet
                CustomViewHolder::class.java,
                mDatabase

        ) {
            override fun populateViewHolder(viewHolder: CustomViewHolder?, model: Utfordringer?, position: Int) {


                if (model != null) {
                    viewHolder?.itemView?.recyclerview_text_1?.text = model.kategori // textViewet som tilhører kategori i RecyclerViewet
                }
                if (model != null) {
                    viewHolder?.itemView?.recyclerview_text_2?.text = model.utfordring // textViewet som tilhører utfordringen i RecyclerViewet
                }


            }
        }

        mRecyclerView.adapter = firebaseRecyclerAdapter
    }

     private fun recyclerViewItemTouchListener() {



        val itemTouchCallback = object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
                return false // False her fordi vi ikke skal flytte på noen av radene, bare Swipe
            }

            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                val pos = viewHolder.adapterPosition // Posisjonen
                mRecyclerView.removeViewAt(pos)
                mRecyclerView.adapter!!.notifyItemRemoved(pos)

            }
        }

        val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchCallback)
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerview_utfordringer)
    }




    // Viewholder
    class CustomViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    }


}
```

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here is an [article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) that does the exact thing that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So, it is not possible to do the same using Realtime Database?

Comment: It certainly does.